# Check pointing is not working with dynamodb streams record in flink

Tags: apache-flink, amazon-dynamodb-streams

How do a checkpoint the processed records in apache flink? same messages are being consumed at regular intervals.

Do I need to explicitly checkpoint each message post consumption?

I can see the `eventId` and `sequenceNumber` are matching for multiple messages being consumed.

It seems the checkpointing is not done and so same messages are retrieved from steams at regular intervals.

Here is the code

```
package com.flink.basics;

import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.ListState;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.ListStateDescriptor;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.functions.KeySelector;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2;
import org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration;
import org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeValue;
import org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.Record;
import org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.PreparedCheckpointer;
import org.apache.flink.runtime.state.filesystem.FsStateBackend;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.CheckpointingMode;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.KeyedStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.SingleOutputStreamOperator;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.CheckpointConfig;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.KeyedProcessFunction;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.DiscardingSink;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.FlinkDynamoDBStreamsConsumer;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.config.AWSConfigConstants;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.config.ConsumerConfigConstants;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.serialization.DynamoDBStreamsSchema;
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector;

import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Properties;

public class DynamoDbConsumer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Properties consumerConfig = new Properties();
        consumerConfig.put(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_REGION, "us-east-1");
        consumerConfig.put(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, "aws_access_key_id");
        consumerConfig.put(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, "aws_secret_access_key");
        consumerConfig.put(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_ENDPOINT, "http://localhost:4566");
        consumerConfig.put(ConsumerConfigConstants.STREAM_INITIAL_POSITION, "LATEST");

        System.setProperty("com.amazonaws.sdk.disableCbor", "true");
        System.setProperty("org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.sdk.disableCbor", "true");

        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        env.enableCheckpointing(1000, CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE);
        env.getCheckpointConfig().setMaxConcurrentCheckpoints(1);

        env.getCheckpointConfig().enableExternalizedCheckpoints(CheckpointConfig.ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup.RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION);
        // File based Backend
        env.setStateBackend(new FsStateBackend(Paths.get("/Users/polimea/flink-basics/stbackend").toUri(), false));

        FlinkDynamoDBStreamsConsumer<Record> flinkConsumer = new FlinkDynamoDBStreamsConsumer<Record>(
                Collections.singletonList("arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:000000000000:table/FDXTable/stream/2022-05-24T00:18:12.500"),
                new DynamoDBStreamsSchema(), consumerConfig);

        DataStream<Record> kinesisDBStream = env.addSource(flinkConsumer);


        KeyedStream<Record, String> snapshotKeyedStream = kinesisDBStream.keyBy((KeySelector<Record, String>)
                record -> record.getDynamodb().getNewImage().get("SNP").getS());

        SingleOutputStreamOperator<Tuple2<String, Record>> records = snapshotKeyedStream.process(new StatefulReduceFunc());
        records.print();
        records.addSink(new DiscardingSink<>());

        snapshotKeyedStream.process(new KeyedProcessFunction<String, Record, Object>() {
            @Override
            public void processElement(Record record, KeyedProcessFunction<String, Record, Object>.Context context,
                                       Collector<Object> collector) throws Exception {

            }
        });

        // kinesisDBStream.print();
        env.execute("Stream for buffering dynamodb records till snapshot is committed");
    }

    private static class StatefulReduceFunc extends KeyedProcessFunction<String, Record, Tuple2<String, Record>> {

        private transient ListState<Record> records;

        public void open(Configuration parameters) {
            ListStateDescriptor<Record> listStateDescriptor =
                    new ListStateDescriptor<>("records", Record.class);
            records = getRuntimeContext().getListState(listStateDescriptor);
        }

        @Override
        public void processElement(Record record, Context context,
                                   Collector<Tuple2<String, Record>> collector) throws Exception {
            Iterable<Record> recordIterator = this.records.get();
            AttributeValue snCommitted = record.getDynamodb().getNewImage().get("SNCommitted");
            if (snCommitted != null && snCommitted.getBOOL()) {
                for (Record recordInList : recordIterator) {
                    collector.collect(new Tuple2<>(record.getDynamodb().getNewImage().get("SNP").getS(), recordInList));
                }
            } else {
                records.add(record);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `same messages are being consumed at regular intervals.` - Do you see this behaviour only after restarting the Flink job or even in a running state you are receiving duplicates?

Comment: I see this behavior both during start up and running state.  It seems the problem is with shard discovery when ever i increase the `shard discovery interval`, the duplicates are delayed by that time.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is related to your issue but the code you provided will buffer the records forever. I think what you want is to emit records and clear the state once commit message comes. Something along those lines

```
// ...
if (snCommitted != null && snCommitted.getBOOL()) {
  var snp = record.getDynamodb().getNewImage().get("SNP").getS();
  for (Record recordInList : recordIterator) {
    collector.collect(new Tuple2<>(snp, recordInList));
  }
  // explicitly clear the buffer not to emit same events over and over again
  records.clear();
}
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I had the code but got removed in the process to fix the reconsumption of the messages.

Comment: @Amareswar has this solved your issue?

Comment: no the clearing of the state is not impacting the offsets, same messages are being consumed after restart with checkpoint.  I think this is something to do with the shard discovery

Comment: It seems the issue is with localstack, `describestreams` command with last seen shard id for a given stream, is returning that shard too in the response which should not be the case.

This makes flink think that a new shard has been discovered and then starts consuming from that shard.

Create a ticket in localstack to look into that

https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/6158