# what is the max list state that i can have in flink using rocksdb state backend

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

Planning to buffer cdc events within flink list state till they are ready to be streamed. What is the max list size that can be supported for a given key?

Answer (score 1):

The serialized list is limited to 2^31 bytes. This is a limitation of the JNI layer.

Comment: Hi David, Can you please answer my question here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72356268/check-pointing-is-not-working-with-dynamodb-streams-record-in-flink/72357937